# Offline first web-app development stack

Tags: web-apps, offline, progressive-web-application

I would like to develop a app which is "offline first".

Which tools/stack do **you** recommend?

Required features:

- The app I create with these tools should work in current browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari) on desktop and mobile. No need to support IE11
- No plugin or native app needs to be installed by users
- open source (not GPL or AGPL run-time dependency)

Background: I want to write a simple chat app where the last N messages are available on the client. This way the user can read while he/she is in a train (offline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with developing progressive web apps, but I enjoyed getting started with [Angular](https://angular.io/). They have a neat tutorial and you get a plain PWA in a breeze (see [Angular service worker introduction](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)). You'll get a service worker, so you don't need to write one yourself.

The development stack for Angular is based on npm, nodejs, TypeScript and unsurprisingly Angular itself.

Angular has an [MIT-Licence](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/LICENSE), so the open source requirement should be covered.

If you make a PWA, the users only need a modern web browser, ne need to install software.

Comment: Sounds good. Don't ask my why. But at the moment everybody seems to be on the ReactJS hype. Thank you, I will look at Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Could [Blazor WebAssembly](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) be an option? I recommend looking into it if you are at all familiar with C# and the .NET ecosystem.